# gunicorn.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning */env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, gunicorn, systemctl

gunicorn.service cannot open WorkingDirectory and the gunicorn executable. I think it's about permissions but I don't know how I can solve it.

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn:**

```
Mar 15 12:12:42 ns1.localhost.com systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 15 12:12:42 ns1.localhost.com systemd[16439]: gunicorn.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Mar 15 12:12:42 ns1.localhost.com systemd[16439]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /home/radarkes-api/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory
Mar 15 12:12:42 ns1.localhost.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Mar 15 12:12:42 ns1.localhost.com systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/radarkes-api/src
ExecStart=/home/radarkes-api/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/radarkes-api/src/core.sock core.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can run **/home/radarkes-api/env/bin/gunicorn** manually, this is the output which means I can access the gunicorn executable:

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

**I tried:**

- Adding "source /home/radarkes-api/env/bin/activate &&" at the start of ExecStart.
- chmod -R 777 /home/radarkes-api

**tree -d -L 2 /home/radarkes-api/:**

```
radarkes-api/
├── env
│   ├── bin
│   └── lib
└── src
    ├── api
    └── core
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? if yes please kindly notify. I am also facing the same problem currently.

Comment: I solved it but I don't remember how, sorry.

Comment: I was using an outdated digital ocean article dated from 2016. So i finally solved it by going through this updated article in which the gunicorn setting was simpler and more straightforward: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecStart` must be a sub-path of `WorkingDirectory`

in your example `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` will look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/radarkes-api/src
ExecStart=/home/radarkes-api/src/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/radarkes-api/src/core.sock core.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**PS:**

1. In your case, it's preferable to create a new virtual env instead of moving your existing `env` folder inside of `src` one (to avoid paths issues),
2. Make sure all your pip3 requirements are available in your `requirements.txt` file,
3. Make sure your `.gitignore` includes the new virtual env folder

Then execute:

```
$ cd /home/radarkes-api/src
$ python3 -m venv MyEnvName
$ echo 'MyEnvName/' >> .gitignore
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```